# loop through array to load data in qlikview

Tags: sql, qlikview

I am loding data in qlikview using statement

```
/ /Importing data from flat file
 dataimport:
 LOAD  @1 AS CoCd,
 @2 AS Period,
 @3 AS [Doc. Date],
 @4 AS [Pstng Date],
 @5 AS TranslDate,
 @6 AS Reference,
 @7 AS DocumentNo,
 @8 AS Crcy,
 @9 AS Year,
 @10 AS [Doc. Type],
 \\cagesre005\*GLDetl*
 (txt, codepage is 1252, no labels, delimiter is ';', msq)


where @10 = 'KA' or @10 = 'KG' or @10 = 'KR' or @10 = 'KH' or @10 = 'KN' or @10 ='AB' or @10 ='IK' or @10 ='IM' or @10 ='MM' or @10 ='RE' or @10 ='RN';
```

this statement loads data perfectly but it is not dynamic since if I want to change the `@10` to some different value I have to make change directly to the script, I am looking for a way that loop through a array containing these values and load data to the table

something like creating variable

`$(vDocTypes) = 'KA','KG','KR','KH','KN','AB','IK','IM','MM','RE' ,'RN';`

which I can use in where clause that goes through the values in the array and load the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the Match function:

```
set vDocTypes= 'KA','KG','KR','KH','KN','AB','IK','IM','MM','RE' ,'RN';

//Importing data from flat file
 dataimport:
    LOAD  
        @1 AS CoCd,
        @2 AS Period,
        @3 AS [Doc. Date],
        @4 AS [Pstng Date],
        @5 AS TranslDate,
        @6 AS Reference,
        @7 AS DocumentNo,
        @8 AS Crcy,
        @9 AS Year,
        @10 AS [Doc. Type]
     From 
        \\cagesre005\*GLDetl* (txt, codepage is 1252, no labels, delimiter is ';', msq)
    Where 
        Match( @10, $(vDocTypes) ) > 0
 ;
```